# getJSON calling format to servlet problem

Tags: servlets, jquery

Hello I am using Jquery getJSON to send a query parameter to servlet. 
The servlet URL works by itself:
http://localhost:8080/pgViking/recentUploads?conID=2

It gives the following output:

```
{reports:[{filename:"CSVFile_2010-06-16T11_54_53.csv"},
        {filename:"CSVFile_2010-06-16T11_54_53.csv"}, <br />
        {filename:"PRJ20142_05_10_2008.zip"}]}
```

However, I cannot get a proper response from jQuery. 
Here is code for it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#cons").change(function(){
            var selected = $("#cons option:selected");
            // getJSON("servlet Name", Selected Value  2, 3, function to show result, callback function
            $.getJSON("recentUploads?conID=", selected.val(), function(data){
                $("#reports").contents().remove();
                    $.each(data.reports, function(index,rpt){
                    // add items to List box
                    $("#reports").append("<option>" + rpt.filename + "</option");
                    } //end function
                    ); //end of each

            }); // getJSON
        }); // change
     });
```

the html part:

```
        <select Name="eCons" size="1"  id="cons">
                <option value="select consultant">Select Consultant</option>
                <option value="4">A</option>
                <option value ="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">Br</option>
                <option value ="21">D</option>
                <option value="20">G</option>
                <option value="24">T</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <select id="reports" style ="width:200px">
        </select>
```

When I debug it in firebug I see that I have incorrect URL but I am not sure
if it's the only problem:
`url="recentUploads?conID=&3"`

Any help it would be appreciated, 
Thanks,

Comment: I think you meant `$(data.reports).each(function())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use jQuery.each function in this way. http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
                for(i in data.reports){
                // add items to List box
                $("#reports").append("<option>" + data.reports[i].filename + "</option");
                ); //end of loop
```

to remove & use:
    $.getJSON("recentUploads?conID="+selected.val(), function(data){

or:

```
$.getJSON("recentUploads",{conID:selected.val()}, function(data){
```

Comment: Where does it say you cannot use `$.each` in this way on that page? I use it like this often with great success, minus the typo I meantioned above.

Comment: Description: Iterate over a **jQuery object**, executing a function for each matched element.
`.each( function(index, Element) )`

Comment: You realize that a jquery object is more than DOM nodes right? See: [jQuery Object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: yeah you can. This usage is out of api

Comment: I think both loops are valid. EACH and FOR. In order to use FOR loop the element should not have any null values.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#reports").append("<option>" + rpt.filename + "</option");
```

This is invalid. The closing tag `>` is not only missing, but this also won't create a real HTML element at all. Use `$("<option>")` to let jQuery create a real HTML `<option>` element.

```
$("#reports").append($("<option>").text(rpt.filename));
```

I'd also suggest to get hold of `$("#reports")` as a `var` before the loop, that's a tad more efficient.

You can find more examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet/4113258#4113258).

Answer (score 2):

the getJSON call expects valid JSON (valid JSON has quotes around the **keys** and **values**, with the only exception being values that are numbers.  The output of your servlet should look like this:

```
    {
        "reports": [
            {
                "filename": "CSVFile_2010-06-16T11_54_53.csv" 
            },
            {
                "filename": "CSVFile_2010-06-16T11_54_53.csv" 
            },
            {
                " filename": "PRJ20142_05_10_2008.zip" 
            } 


  ]

}
```

Otherwise, you can use the jQuery ajax call, giving the dataType attribute a value of "text" and using this code in the success function:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
        $.getJSON("recentUploads", { 'conID': selected.val()}, function(data){
           $("#reports").contents().remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Parameters are: url, data (map or string), callback.

This is way an ampersand (&) is used to join your url + paramenter passed as string (3). As result you have: recentUploaded?conID=&3